# Setting a custom log path

Tags: vb.net

According to the information on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.logging(v=vs.110).aspx) I should be able to set the CustomLocation property of the FileLogTraceListener.  In doing so, I'm finding that the logging stops when I go away from using the default property.  I'm not real sure what I could be doing wrong here.  What am I missing?

```
Module PackingListPrintModule

  'Establish application path, replace appPath on deployment
  Public appPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
  Public Property CustomLocation As String
    Public logtrace As New FileLogTraceListener

  Function setCustomLogLocation() As String
      logtrace.CustomLocation = appPath
      setCustomLogLocation = appPath
  End Function

      Sub Main()

        Try
            'Test use the logtrace instace to write a line
            logtrace.Append = True
            logtrace.WriteLine("Set the log and application path to" & setCustomLogLocation())

           'Test use of the Log.WriteEntry method to write a line (Works with default settings)
                My.Application.Log.WriteEntry("Checking that save location exists")
                logtrace = Nothing

        Catch ex as Exception
              msgbox(ex.Message)
        Finally
              logtrace = Nothing
              Environment.Exit(0)
        End Sub
    End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the **FileLog** location and name using:

```
My.Application.Log.DefaultFileLogWriter.CustomLocation = "LOG_DIRECTORY_PATH"    
My.Application.Log.DefaultFileLogWriter.BaseFileName = "LOG_NAME"
```